# How can bind items details from the listview in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, pos

I need help on how to achive binding items from the list view into other widget. For example, I have a listview of Products to be sold, when a sale person click any product from the list, it should be added on top of the screen with it price, then more product can be added each time a sale person press new product from the listview. I have already tried different ways to achieve this. This is a sample of the screen I want to achieve.[image]

This is what I have achieved so far

```
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NewSale extends StatefulWidget {
  const NewSale({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NewSaleState createState() => _NewSaleState();
}

class _NewSaleState extends State<NewSale> {
  TextEditingController searchingInput = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.green),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0.0,
        title: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
              child: Text(
                "Sales",
                style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff444444), fontSize: 19),
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              "Manage Sales",
              style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffa1a1a1), fontSize: 13),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        actions: [
          Builder(
              builder: (context) => IconButton(
                    icon: Image.asset("assets/images/icons/sync_products.png"),
                    onPressed: () => {},
                  )),
        ],
        leading: Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.arrow_back,
                color: Colors.black,
                size: 40, // Changing Drawer Icon Size
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: new Container(
        height: 70.0,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Flexible(
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    MaterialButton(
                      elevation: 0.00,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          side: BorderSide(
                              color: Color(0xffFA7659),
                              width: 1,
                              style: BorderStyle.solid),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3)),
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      color: Color(0xffFA7659),
                      child: Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
                                child: Text('CLEAR',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 16,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300)),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    MaterialButton(
                      elevation: 0.00,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          side: BorderSide(
                              color: Color(0xff78BD42),
                              width: 1,
                              style: BorderStyle.solid),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3)),
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      color: Color(0xff78BD42),
                      child: Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
                                child: Text(
                                  'CONFIRM',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Flexible(
                child: Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .5,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      '==== Product Cart ====',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff5c5c5c)),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .5,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 10, 0, 0),
                                child: MaterialButton(
                                  elevation: 0.00,
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      side: BorderSide(
                                          color: Color(0xff828282),
                                          width: 1,
                                          style: BorderStyle.solid),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3)),
                                  textColor: Colors.white,
                                  color: Color(0xff828282),
                                  child: Row(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: [
                                      Column(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                        children: [
                                          Row(
                                            children: [
                                              Image.asset(
                                                'assets/images/icons/scan.png',
                                                width: 20,
                                                height: 20,
                                              ),
                                              Padding(
                                                padding:
                                                    const EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
                                                child: Text('SCAN',
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: 16,
                                                        color: Colors.white,
                                                        fontWeight:
                                                            FontWeight.w300)),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {},
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: Column(
                              children: [productSearchingField()],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: [
                          Flexible(
                            child: Container(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 7, 15, 0),
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  MaterialButton(
                                    elevation: 0.00,
                                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        side: BorderSide(
                                            color: Color(0xff78BD42),
                                            width: 1,
                                            style: BorderStyle.solid),
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3)),
                                    textColor: Colors.white,
                                    color: Color(0xff78BD42),
                                    child: Row(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      children: [
                                        Column(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                          children: [
                                            Row(
                                              children: [
                                                Column(
                                                  children: [Icon(Icons.add)],
                                                ),
                                                Column(
                                                  children: [
                                                    Padding(
                                                      padding:
                                                          const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                              top: 14.0,
                                                              bottom: 14.0),
                                                      child: Text(
                                                        'ADD NEW PRODUCT',
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                            fontSize: 14,
                                                            color: Colors.white,
                                                            fontWeight:
                                                                FontWeight
                                                                    .w300),
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () {},
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Flexible(
                        child: Container(
                          child: ListView.builder(
                              itemCount: 10,
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                return ListTile(
                                  leading: Image.asset(
                                    'assets/images/icons/brand-identity.png',
                                    width: 50,
                                    height: 50,
                                  ),
                                  trailing: Text(
                                    "100,000",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.green, fontSize: 15),
                                  ),
                                  title: Text("This is item $index"),
                                  subtitle: Text('Electronics'),
                                );
                              }),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  productSearchingField() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 10, 15, 0),
      height: 60,
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: searchingInput,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          labelText: 'Search Product or Barcode',
          prefixIcon: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Icon(
                Icons.search,
                color: Colors.black54,
              )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code-snippet that you've tried so far?

Comment: I added the code which result the above shared design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i manage to do this using the below code hope it will work for you

```
  class _DummyDesignState extends State<DummyDesign> {

  List<String> ShoppingItems = ['Ball', 'Clet', 'JoyStick'];
  List<String> PurchasedItem = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('List length is ${ShoppingItems.length}');
    print('List length is ${PurchasedItem.length}');
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Hello'),
        ),
        body: PurchasedItem.isEmpty
            ? Center(
                child: Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: ShoppingItems.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return ListTile(
                            onTap: (){
                              PurchasedItem.add(ShoppingItems[index]);
                              setState(() {

                              });
                            },
                            leading: Icon(Icons.list),
                            title: Text(
                              ShoppingItems[index],
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green, fontSize: 15),
                            ));
                      }),
                ),
              )
            : Center(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: PurchasedItem.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return Text(PurchasedItem[index]);
                            }),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: ShoppingItems.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return ListTile(
                                onTap: (){
                                  PurchasedItem.add(ShoppingItems[index]);
                                  setState(() {

                                  });
                                },
                                  leading: Icon(Icons.list),
                                  title: Text(
                                    ShoppingItems[index],
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green, fontSize: 15),
                                  ));
                            }),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy.... This is all I need